# Is xvda1 taking up all my disk space on ec2

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

When I log into my ec2 ubuntu instance, I can not download files. I see this error

```
OSError: No space left on device
```

When I run this

```
(python3) ubuntu@ip-172-30-1-208:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             30G     0   30G   0% /dev
tmpfs           6.0G  8.9M  6.0G   1% /run
/dev/xvda1       93G   93G     0 100% /
tmpfs            30G     0   30G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            30G     0   30G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       92M   92M     0 100% /snap/core/8689
/dev/loop1       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/8039
/dev/loop2       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1480
/dev/loop4       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1566
tmpfs           6.0G   24K  6.0G   1% /run/user/1000
```

It looks like all my hard disk, 93G is taken up by `xvda1`. Am I reading this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root file system is full

Usually, this happens on servers when the logging goes awry

My tip is, log in, become root and then `cd /var/log` and run `du -smc *`

This may well take a while but will show you where the big logs are

Note that deleting an in-use logfile will not usually free up disk space

Answer (score 4):

This happened because root is full.

You can find which files are using more space by using the following command.

```
sudo find / -type f -size +10M -exec ls -lh {} \;
```

After that delete large files using rm command

```
rm -f <path-to-large-file>
```